# Looping over a csv, trying to write to another csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm looping over a csv of links, visiting those links, and then trying to write information from those links to a new file:

```
with open("hrefs.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        newUrl = row[0]

        response = requests.get(newUrl)
        newData = response.text
        newSoup = BeautifulSoup(newData, 'lxml')
        newstring = ''

        titles = newSoup.findAll('span', {'id': 'titletextonly'})
        prices = newSoup.findAll('span', {'class': 'price'})
        newstring += titles[0].text + ',' + prices[0].text + ','
        for ana in newSoup.findAll('p',{'class':'attrgroup'}):
            for myb in ana.findAll('b'):
                newstring += myb.text + ','
        print newstring
        listFile = open("output.csv", 'wb')
        writer = csv.writer(listFile)
        writer.writerow(newstring.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
```

There are a couple problems I'm running into. **First**, I thought the csv would realize that there are comma separated values and put each attribute in a new column. **Second**, it seems that one letter is getting put in each column. When I simple `print` each `newstring` it is giving me a coherent string.

Comment: `writer.writerow` expects a list/tuple to represent a row. Instead, you give it a string, which is a sequence, so it assumes that each individual letter is to be in its own column as it iterates through the string. I don't really have experience with BeatutifulSoup though so I can't visualise how to put it right from the responses you're getting.

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to have a comma contained within a string written to a single "cell" in a CSV. The `csv` module has no way of knowing whether you actually want to split on every comma it encounters; it relies on you telling it how to separate the data by providing a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give `writer.writerow` a sequence of strings:

```
writer.writerow(newstring.split(","))
```

would be the easiest change from what you currently have.

Comment: I did `writer.writerow(newstring.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii').split(","))`, and it wrote the first couple lines, but then broke, with message `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Line 45 from the csv:   `File "example.py", line 45, in <module> newstring += titles[0].text + ',' + prices[0].text + ',' IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: So that's a problem with the incoming data. You parse it with BeautifulSoup, and expect to get titles and prices. The `IndexError` is basically saying that one or both of the previous two lines failed to get anything. `titles` and `prices` will be empty lists.

Comment: Oh I see - is there a way to handle exceptions?

Comment: Indeed there is! Learn about try...except: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions or https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html